# IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I want to configure Spring Cloud security OAuth2 to apply diffrent permissions:

`/oauth/token` - httpBasic should be applied

`/oauth/revoke` - httpBasic should NOT be applied

I tried this:

```
           http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            // Configure token authentication permissions
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/oauth/token")
                .and()
            // Configure token revoke permissions
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/oauth/revoke").permitAll()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

When I run the code I get error:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest`

Do you know how this configuration can be applied properly?

Answer (score 0):

"Can't configure **antMatchers** after **anyRequest**"
Hello, try to put your antMatchers before anyRequest

Comment: I get `    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"`